# KeyTool.efi - Can not add new db key in user mode - Secure Boot

Tags: uefi, secure-boot

On virtual machine with OVMF implementation of Tianocore UEFI, I ran signed Keytool.efi (Part of efitools-1.5.3-1.1.x86_64 ) initially in Setup Mode.

I inserted db  (signed by KEK Private) , KEK (signed by PK private)  & PK (self signed) and put the platform in User Mode.

Now while in User Mode again using  Keytool.efi I tried to add a new db key (that's also signed by KEK private)  to the signature database where it throws error 
‘Failed to update variable: (26) Security Violation’

I can replace the existing db key here without issues in user mode, however despite  PK, KEK & db are already signed, it throws security violation when trying to add new key.

I searched net but nothing much was found about this error.  Is this expected behavior or am I missing something. Any clarification or help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: IIRC, KeyTool requires that files in in `.auth` format to load them when in user mode.

Comment: Thanks Rod for the comment. Yes I understand, KeyTool requires .auth file in User Mode. With some more experiments and reading thru the documentation of sign-efi-sig-list (That I was using to generate .auth) I figured it out myself after a while. In order to add another key to db in User Mode the .auth needs to be generated with -a switch  (Prepare the variable for APPEND_WRITE rather than replacement)   which I was completely missing.